# Gmail open tracking, set cookie with Django

Tags: python, django, email, cookies, gmail

I'm working on a simple app to embed a transparent pixel into emails being sent out manually with Gmail and then cookie the user.

I'm inserting this `<img>` into the email:

```
<img height="1" src="https://example.net/pixel.png?guid=1234" style="visibility:" width="1">
```

The intent is that when the email is opened it should request the image from `example.net/pixel.png`

The Django app with an endpoint of `pixel.png` has this view:

```
def set_cookie(request):
    PIXEL_GIF_DATA = "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
    data = base64.b64decode(PIXEL_GIF_DATA)
    response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='image/gif')
    response.set_cookie('some_cookie_name', 'some_cookie_value')
    return response
```

If I visit `example.net/pixel.png?guid=1234' it's setting the cookie appropriately, so we're good there.

The only issue I'm running into is that when the email is opened the request is not being made out to my server. As the recipient if I go into the developer tools and watch the network requests I'm not seeing the request being made to `mysite.net`

However, if I view the original email, down in the footer I can see that my `<img>` tag is included.

If I try using an external image like `static.example.net/images/sometest123.png` the image does come through and is visible.

Answer (score 2):

[Gmail fetches the image and caches it on its servers](https://www.wired.com/2013/12/turn-gmail-auto-image-loading-off/), to prevent this kind of tracking and protect the recipient's privacy.

Comment: there are plenty of services that offer email open tracking: Yesware, Cirrus, Marketo, etc., etc. - https://www.computerworld.com/article/2979569/web-browsers/review-6-chrome-extensions-let-you-track-your-gmail.html

Comment: There might be plenty of services that offer email open tracking, but if Gmail loads images through a proxy, then your cookie setting won't do any good.

Comment: I work with email a lot and I can confirm that this is how Gmail works. You know that your recipient just opened your email and that the device used to open the email was Gmail's server. Personally I like this approach.